# How can I cancel an alarm in a service?

Tags: android, android-alarms

I used a service to update an appwidget and also scheduled a repeating alarm for periodic updates (i.e it still calls the service class). my problem now is, I don't know how to cancel the alarm and stop the service when an appwidget is deleted from the home screen. I have tried cancelling the alarm in onDeleted() of the appwidget with the same pending intent that created the alarm, but its not cancelling it.

Here is the code for the service schedule:

```
Intent widgetUpdate = new Intent();
widgetUpdate.setClass(this, appService.class);  
//widgetUpdate.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);  
widgetUpdate.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, new int[]{appWidgetId});
//widgetUpdate.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse(URI_SCHEME + "://widget/id/"),
  String.valueOf(appWidgetId));
widgetUpdate.setData(data);

PendingIntent newpending = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, widgetUpdate,
  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 
  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+ updateRate, updateRate, newpending);
```

then in the onDeleted() of appWidgetProviderClass:

```
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {

  for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) { 
    //cancel the alarm
    Intent widgetUpdate = new Intent();
    //widgetUpdate.setClassName(this, appService.class);
    //Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse(URI_SCHEME + "://widget/id/"),
    //  String.valueOf(appWidgetId));
    //widgetUpdate.setData(data);
    PendingIntent newpending  = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, widgetUpdate,
      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarm = 
      (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.cancel(newpending);
    //cancel the service
    context.stopService(new Intent(context,WeatherService.class);    
  }
  super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
}
```

please could you point out if am doing anything wrong? Thanks.

just a side note, have left those commented codes, just to let you guys know i have tried that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `PendingIntent` with `cancel()` that is equivalent to the one you used with `setRepeating()`. In other words:

- If you call `setClass()` on the `setRepeating()` `Intent`, you need to call the same `setClass()` on the `cancel()` Intent
- If you call `setAction()` on the `setRepeating()` `Intent`, you need to call the same `setAction()` on the `cancel()` Intent
- If you call `setData()` on the `setRepeating()` `Intent`, you need to call the same `setData()` on the `cancel()` Intent

Extras do not matter, but the component (class), action, data (`Uri`), and MIME type all matter.

Comment: gosh thanks,i can enjoy my sunday now, i was wondering what i was doing wrong. by the way, if i may ask, do you think its a good design or idea to schedule the repeating alarm in the service class. i tried doing it in a configuration class, but it never happened. i don't know if its because the configuration class calls this service class.

Comment: @user712109: Sorry, I cannot answer that question in the abstract. I don't know what "the configuration class" is, etc.

Comment: oh sorry, i meant the user sets the update rate from the configuration class and thats how the alarm gets the value to schedule; from preferences since the configuration class has to update the widget initially, which it does from the service class. but since its not part of the question, won't bother you with that. Thanks again

Comment: Anyways, all i wanted to say was that as long as there is nothing wrong with doing all the work from a service, then its fine. Thanks! :)